# Links not working with position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a `div` with a absolute position and a `div` with relative position. The first `div` contains the links and the second `div` contains some contents which is over the first `div`. The first `div` has a `z-index` of 1, while the second has a `z-index` of -1 and the first `div` is also declared first.

Although, the links in the first `div` are unclickable. I have now idea, why this is so.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyilo/XjUU8/1/)

Both `side1` and `side2` will have a background image. And the content should appear over the sides, but the links should still work.

[Second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyilo/XjUU8/1/)

Comment: With your edit, you can't have it work like that with your HTML you provided - that would have to change. You have `.side1` which should appear under the `#content`, but you want `.side1 #books` to appear above `#content` - that won't work. If you move `#books` ouside of `.side1` it becomes pretty easy to get it set up how (I think) you want it, is that OK? See http://jsfiddle.net/3d7bc/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either change `.side` to have `z-index: 1`, or change `#container` to have `margin-top: 150px` instead of `padding-top`.

`#books` has a `z-index` of 1, but it's inside a container with a `z-index` of -1, so it still ends up below the `#container` which has `z-index: -1` but gets rendered after (thus on top).

Comment: +1 the z-index really works wonder when an a tag is contained in a position:absolute element (position:relative of the a tag was needed as well for my scenario).

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have

```
            z-index: -1;
            position: absolute;
```

I think this is the reason. Changing `-1`  to `1` fixes it. Not sure if I'm missing something, if so, please explain in comments and/or update the question.

Answer (score 1):

the links are unclickable because a div tag is over leaping it.

This tag:

```
  <div class="side side2"></div>
```

give the .side2 element a lower z-index to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first div and your second div, both share the class `.side`, which is defined with a `z-index: -1`. So both are on the same stack level and the one that comes last in the markup will be on top of the previous. All you have to do is to give `.side1` a z-index bigger than -1.